# Google map localization

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

How do I tell google map's geocoder API to use english not the browser's default languange?

For example,
User's OS language is French and when he use the website and querying for london, it returns angleterre, londres

is there a way to force the geocoding to return EN_GB locale? So it returns: United kingdom, london.

And also if the user is Chinese, it'll return everything in chinese. How can I avoid this?

Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to avoid this. For example, wouldn't a Chinese user want results in Chinese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Geocode API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#Audience)

You can set the language parameter

> language (optional) — The language in
>   which to return results. See the
>   supported list of domain languages.
>   Note that we often update supported
>   languages so this list may not be
>   exhaustive. If language is not
>   supplied, the geocoder will attempt to
>   use the native language of the domain
>   from which the request is sent
>   wherever possible.
>
> The map controls, tooltips, and
>   copyrights have been translated for a
>   subset of languages, listed in the
>   spreadsheet below. The API will sense
>   the browser settings of the user and
>   set the language appropriately. It is
>   possible to override the language in
>   the APIs; more information is
>   available in the JavaScript API
>   documentation and the Flash API
>   reference.

For Example:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=japan&sensor=false&language=en
```

returns in English

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=japan&sensor=false&language=zh-CN
```

returns in Chinese